# How can I structure a voting system in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes and relationships like this:

`(u:User)`

`(t:Topic)-[r:HAS_FACT]->(t:Fact)`

`(t2:Topic)-[r2:HAS_FACT]->(t:Fact)`

or, simplified:

`(t:Topic)-[r:HAS_FACT]->(t:Fact)<-[r2:HAS_FACT]-(t2:Topic)`

Where users can upload `Facts` and tie them to `Topics`. Because of the craziness of the internet I'd like to add a voting system that enables users to support/validate/upvote facts, but they don't just upvote the Facts, they need to upvote the combination of Topic and Fact. So really I think they'd be upvoting r and r2?

Essentially I'd like to tie `User` nodes to some sort of voting system that is somehow tied to a combination of `Fact` and `Topic` nodes. I'm not against restructuring anything at this point, happy to do it if there is a more logical solution here!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep track of the the votes of any particular combination of `Fact`, `Topic` and `User`.

To do this you'll need to insert a new type of node into the graph that can keep track of this for you for which I can see two options — tally all the votes on a single node per topic / fact combination or have one vote per topic / fact / user.

Single node per topic / fact would look like

```
(:Topic)<-[VOTES_FOR_TOPIC]-(votes:Votes {sum: 10})-[:VOTES_FOR_FACT]->(:Fact)
// Each Votes node will have multiple users
(u1:User)-[:UPVOTED]->(votes)
(u2:User)-[:DOWNVOTED]->(votes)
```

Note that I have assumed that you can downvote and upvote, but if you can only upvote it does not make much of a difference.

The alternative is one `Vote` node per user/topic/fact comvination. This would look the same as above apart from that there will only be one `:User` per `:Vote` node. Assuming each vote would have a 1 if it is positive and a -1 if it is negative you could get the full tally for a combination of fact and topic by

```
MATCH (t:Topic) WHERE id(t) = $topic_id
MATCH (f:Fact) WHERE id(f) = $fact_id
MATCH (t)<-[:VOTES_FOR_TOPIC]-(vote:Vote)-[:VOTES_FOR_FACT]->(:Fact)
RETURN sum(vote.value)
```

Either of these two solutions would work for you I think. Note that you're essentially implementing a [hyperedge](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperedge.html) which in Neo4j is done using an extra node.

Comment: Wow this is a great idea, it's so obvious now. Just to ensure I understand, the first one would count how many relationships there are from that one node, the second would sum up how many Vote node graphs there are that link to topic and fact nodes?

What I'm thinking I'll do is have one vote note for a topic / fact combination, then I'll have multiples users -> that vote node and then connect that vote node to a topic and to a fact. This feels like it can easily scale to anything that might require voting in the future.

Thank you a ton, really obvious now!

Comment: > ust to ensure I understand, the first one would count how many relationships there are from that one node, the second would sum up how many Vote node graphs there are that link to topic and fact nodes?

Yup, that sounds about right! The first implementation is probably the one that scales better as you say.